# Копирование одномерного массива в двумерный массив

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы, копирование

У меня есть домашнее задание, в котором требуется:

> Написать метод, который принимает два параметра: массив `int[]` и число `int`, которое означает количество элементов. Метод должен вернуть двумерный массив, который является результатом деления переданного одномерного массива на строки указанной длины. Последняя строка может содержать элементов меньше, если длина массива не делится на цело на количество элементов. Например, если массив `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` и число `4`, то метод должен вернуть двухмерный массив `{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9}}`.

Пытался решить задачу с помощью этого кода:

```java
public static int[][] convert1DTo2D(int[] a, int n) {
    int columns = n;
    int rows = a.length / columns;
    double s = (double) a.length / (double) columns;
    if (s % 2 != 0) {
        rows += 1;
    }
    int[][] b = new int[rows][columns];
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (count == a.length) break;
            b[i][j] = a[count];
            count++;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Появилась проблема, когда пытаюсь вывести новый массив, выводит:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Как мне убрать три нуля на конце? При условии, что нельзя использовать методы из пакета `java.util.*` или какие-либо другие встроенные методы для этого.

Comment: лично я вообще не знаю способа создавать динамическую лохматую матрицу в джаве.  единственное, что вы можете, это сделать из массива int массив Integer, в этом случае вместо 0 будет null

Comment: @Дмитрий лохматый пример ниже. :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```java
public static int[][] convert1DTo2D(int[] arr, int n) {
    // количество строк
    int m = arr.length / n + (arr.length % n == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    // длина последней строки
    int lastRow = arr.length % n == 0 ? n : arr.length % n;
    // новый массив
    int[][] arr2 = new int[m][];
    // заполнение
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int[] row = new int[i < m - 1 ? n : lastRow];
        for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            row[j] = arr[j + i * n];
        }
        arr2[i] = row;
    }
    return arr2;
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int[][] arr2 = convert1DTo2D(arr1, 4);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr2));
    // [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как- то так

```
public static int[][] convert1DTo2D(int[] a, int n) {
    int columns = n;
    int rows = a.length / columns;
    double s = (double) a.length / (double) columns;
    if (s % 2 != 0) {
      rows += 1;
    }
    int[][] b = new int[rows][];
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      b[i] = (i + 1 < rows) ? new int[columns] : new int[a.length % columns];
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        if (count == a.length) break;
        b[i][j] = a[count];
        count++;
      }
    }
    return b;
  }
```

Comment: Если ответ помог разобраться то галочка под стрелками

Comment: @Aziz Umarov за очень много лет никогда так не извращался и понятия не имею, зачем это нужно, но очень интересно)))